# We throw a die $6$ times. What is the probability of getting exactly two 6s?

Tags: probability

We throw a die $6$ times. What is the probability of getting exactly two 6s?

Let $S:$"The set of solutions" then $|S|=6^6$

Let $E:$"Get $2$ 6's" a event. We need calculate $|E|$

If we throw a die 6 times, then we obtain in two of six results, two 6s.

Then $|E|=2$

In consequence,

The probability of getting exactly two 6s is $\frac{2}{6^6}$

Is the reasoning good?

Comment: Nop. You need to evaluate in how many *different* forms two $\;6\,$'s can come up out of 6 throws...Binomial coefficient rings a bell?

Comment: you should clarify whether you mean "exactly $2$" or "at least $2$".

Comment: is exactly. @lulu

Comment: Thanks.  I'd edit the text to clarify that, though.  I think most people would guess that you meant "exactly" but it's ambiguous as it stands.

Comment: i think is ${6}\choose{2}$ no? @DonAntonio

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

Guide:

Assume that each throw is independent, view getting a $6$ as a success event in a single throw. What is the probability that you get a $6$ in a single throw?

Note that out of $6$ throws, the number of successful throw follows the Binomial distribution, try to identify its parameters and use its formula.

Answer (score 1):

You're question is a classic, text book, of a binomial distribution where the given variables are:

1. Probability of success (in one trial) = 1/6
2. Number of trials: 6
3. desired number of success = 2 (exactly!)

so  ${6\choose 2}*(\frac{1}{6})^2*(1-\frac{1}{6})^4=0.2009$

Comment: You mean trial rather than trail.

Comment: :-) @N. F. Taussig correct! changed. thanks